# Unity tweak tool - make the Launcher fully transparent?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-tweak-tool

I want my Launcher to be transparent, so I check "Transparency" in Unity tweak tool and... it's solid. When I uncheck the transparency button... it is transparency. I've made gif to show it clearly.

How to make the launcher **fully transparent**?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is [bug #1168834](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1168834). The bug has been fixed in the source but has not landed in the Ubuntu archive.

Comment: Bug is fix release already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a bug. Maybe it’s because CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) uses Opacity instead, so when you set Transparency OFF, probably it sets the Opacity equal to 0; thus it’s transparent. So if you want to make it totally transparent, you should move the slider position once and then put it on the **tranparency 100%** and also choose **black** for custom color, otherwise, it won’t be fully transparent. Here’s some screenshots:

Transparency 100% with a wallpaper-based color: it’s not transparent!

[image: Launcher transparency 100% with wallpaper-based color]

Transparency 100% with white: it’s not transparent but rather shiny!

[image: Launcher transparency 100% with white color]

Transparency 100% with black: it’s really transparent, but COF icon has a black background.

[image: Launcher transparency 100% with black color]

Transparency OFF with black: the same result as transparency 100%. Turning the transparency off means 100% tranparency (Opacity OFF)!

[image: Launcher transparency OFF with black]

**Notes:**

1. If you make the Launcher transparent, you may also want to change **Icon backgrounds** to *All applications*.
2. The default value (correct position) for Launcher transparency is on the line about the middle of the range (40%).

Answer (score 0):

When setting transparency on, you have to adjust the transparency level with the slider just below the switch (on your screen capture it's at 100% so... plain solid indeed!)

Then, the fact that the launcher is still transparent when transparency is unchecked might be a bug. If you open CompizConfig (module 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin', tab 'Launcher') and the Unity Tweak Tool at the same time, you can see that the opacity is updated to 0 (ie. invisible) in CompizConfig when you uncheck the transparency option in Unity Tweak Tool.

Comment: This slider is buggy too. Doesn't matter when I set it. 
@AliNa 
Thank you for help.